# Is there a way to disable Browser Close[X] button?

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a working solution wherein an Opportunity is closed(won/lost), a pop up opens and series of work is done(like a wizard).

The pop up is created as per the below code:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <script>    
    if('{!opportunity.StageName}' == 'Closed Won'){
       window.open('/apex/CustomVFPage?id={!opportunity.Id}&retURL=/{!opportunity.Id}','Popup','height=250,width=1000,left=100,top=100,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
    }    
    </script>
    </apex:page>
```

Is there a possibility to disable the Close[X] button on this pop up(browser close). Or Is there a way to embed this CustomVFPage in frame without a close button on it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't disable the close button on any web site. This would be a major security concern. You can, however, use [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) to *ask* the user if they really want to leave, but they can still continue to close the window if they desire. Alterntively, you could use an iframe, but the parent window would still be closable. There's no way to "force" a user to follow your policy.

Comment: Very true @sfdcfox, one disclaimer though about onbeforeunload: "Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all."

Comment: Is there a way that I open my CustomVFPage in a popup window without a Close[X] button?

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar No, there's no way to force the user to keep a window open. In some early browsers, this was possible, which led to situations where a user's computer could be taken over by a website completely, rendering the computer unusable without restarting it. Modern browsers have security protection in place to prevent the very thing you're trying to do.